# Prove that if $(12)(34),(12345)\in G$, it is not solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, solvable-groups

> Let $G$ be a group acting on $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$. Given that there exist two elements $g,h\in G$ so that
>   $$ g(a)=b,\ g(b)=c, \ g(c)=d, \ g(d)=e,
> \\ h(a)=b, \ h(b)=a, \ h(c)=d, \ h(d) =c.
> $$
>   Show that $G$ is not solvable.

**My attempt:** I looked at the homomorphism $\varphi:G\to\operatorname{Aut} X\cong S_5, g\mapsto(x\mapsto g(x))$. We can see that $g$ maps to $(12345)$, and $h$ maps to $(12)(34)$. Here is where I got stuck - how does this help showing $G$ is not solvable?

Comment: My guess is that those two elements generate $A_5$, so you have a surjective homomorphism $\varphi: G \to A_5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $H = \langle(1~2)(3~4), (1~2~3~4~5) \rangle \subseteq A_5$.  Note that $H$ has elements of orders $2$ and $5$ so its order is a multiple of $10$.  It's also easy to see that $H$ contains a $3$-cycle (the commutator of the generating elements is a $3$-cycle), so in fact $30$ must divide the order of $H$.

But $A_5$ is simple so it cannot have any subgroups of index $2$.  Thus, $\vert H \vert \neq 30$ so $\vert H \vert = 60$ and $H=A_5$.  We know that $A_5$ is not solvable and it is a homomorphic image of $G$, so $G$ has a composition series with a non-solvable factor, which means $G$ cannot be solvable.

Comment: I am missing two parts: why is the fact that $H$ cannot be of index $2$ in $A_5$ means that $H=A_5$? And why does the image of $G$ under $\varphi$ being insolvable implies that $G$ isn't?

Comment: As for the first part, $H$ has elements of orders $2, 3, 5$ so it must have order at least $30$, which means (since \vert A_5$ \vert 60$ that $H$ has order $30$ or $60$.  So if the order isn't $30$ (and it can't be), then it must have order $60$.

Comment: As for the second part, you have a subnormal series (which can be refined to a composition series) with a non-trivial, non-solvable factor.  This means that all composition series have that property as well, so $G$ isn't solvable.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand this argument. If there exists a composition series of $G$, what does that imply about the series of $H$?

Comment: You have it backwards.  Essentially, you're using the fact that any group with a non-solvable homomorphic image (in this case, $A_5$) is necessarily itself non-solvable.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thank you.